# Remove 'Content-Type' header in ngResource angular

Tags: angularjs, header, content-type, ngresource

I am new to angular . In my application, i want to upload a file to the server . according to the api , 'Content-Type' header should be null or not sent. I googled  and developers proposed to set the header as undefined . The below is my code

```
return $resource(apiHost +'/tessters/:patId?action=:action&format=:format', {patId: '@patId' , action: '@action' ,format: '@format'}, {
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type' : undefined,'Authorization': authorizationToken},
            }
        });
```

but in the developer view , i am able to observe that the 'Content-Type' is set to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

[image]

and i could not be able to find any ways to remove 'Content-Type' header , If anyone knows the solutions please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried 'Content-Type': 'None'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check below

```
      var file = angular.element(document.querySelector('#file')).prop("files")[0]; $scope.files = []; $scope.files.push(file)
      $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: siteRootURL,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                transformRequest: function (data) {formData.append('model', angular.toJson(data.model));                       
                    formData.append('file', data.files[0]);
                    return formData;
                },
                data: {model: $scope.user,files: $scope.files}
            })
```

Please also check you have set form **enctype='multipart/form-data'** attribute.

Comment: sorry , did not work , i am looking for a way to remove 'Content-Type' , so the  'Content-Type' and bounty will be set automatically..

Comment: Hi , I am using this like below:-

Comment: var file =   angular.element(document.querySelector('#file')).prop("files")[0];
                //Getting the properties of file from file field
                $scope.files = [];
                $scope.files.push(file);

Comment: $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: siteRootURL,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                    transformRequest: function (data) {formData.append('model', angular.toJson(data.model));                       
                        formData.append('file', data.files[0]);
                        return formData;
                    },
                    data: {model: $scope.user,files: $scope.files}
                })

Comment: Tell me if more help required

Comment: Thanks alot ! saved my day